# Proper way to start/continue runloop

Tags: iphone, objective-c

While I usually make use of NSOperation for having a thread do a short task/operation, I'd like to have a long-living dedicated thread that is always available to process certain operations.  For this, I allocate a new NSThread and use the initWithTarget method:

```
- (id)initWithTarget:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector  object:(id)argument
```

My understanding is the selector passed in should be the thread's main method that is responsible for starting the runloop.  What is the proper code to have in there?

Is a while loop like this appropriate...

```
(void)newThreadMainMethod {
    while(1) {
      [[NSThread currentThread] run];
    }
}
```

or is there a more efficient way to do it so that the thread doesn't take up resources with a endless loop?  I was thinking along the lines of having a timer wake up every 0.5 seconds and call run on the thread in case something new is available to work on.  I would appreciate your input.

Thanks.

Comment: I would definitely profile to make sure that this is actually faster than NSOperation, because it seems pretty likely that NSOperationQueue already does what you're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run]` is what you want, but it will carry on forever so you only need to call it once (not in a loop). You can either:

- do that, terminating the thread from within the run loop when/if appropriate
- use `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate: [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: JIFFY_TIME]`, and poll for an exit condition in a `while()` loop like you've written.

Comment: My experience is that calling run will cause the NSThread to terminate if nothing has been put on the thread yet. Is the only way to keep it alive by putting a while loop around run with a condition?

Comment: If you need it to stay around, add a source.

Comment: I've read about sources...Can you give me an example how to add a source?

Comment: There's info at the following link but it seems confusing...

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW7

Comment: actually listings 3-3 to 3-8 in that page do exactly what you need.